# iOS share image and text to UIActivityViewController then getting errors in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel, uiactivityviewcontroller

While share image like normal image it will work fine. But when getting image from `UIImageView` and share it throwing an error.

how to resolve this issue? 
and share image.

Where is issue in my code.

```
NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Address: \n %@",self.label.text];
    UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[title, image] applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[MFMailComposeInternalViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil.'
```

Comment: You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581389/how-do-i-use-uiactivityitemprovider-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-with-uiacti

Comment: @QuocNguyen I am not sharing only in email but share also in another app.

Comment: You are sending nil data here, means image not getting from self.imageView.image. You check this if(self.imageView.image == nil) {  } else { UIImage *image = self.imageView.image; //and write remaking code here }

Comment: @ChiragKothiya you can check when `activityType` is Mail for avoid the crash

Comment: @QuocNguyen Then in other app

Answer (score 1):

Your attach that you are sharing is `nil`, is the reason you are getting a crash at run time.

before attaching an attachment you need to check wether attachment file is available or not.

for eg.

```
if (self.imageView.image == nil) {
    NSLog("image not available.")
    return
}
```