# UIActivity without reading a stored file into into memory?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

My app writes huge images (billions of pixels).

The image is too large to read as a `UIImage` or as `Data`.

Typically, when I share images with an activity controller, I do this:

```
var data: Data
data = ...
activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [data], applicationActivities: [purchaseCanvasPrintActivity])
```

Is it possible to pass a `URL` or something that points to the stored file than having to be allocated in a `Data` object or accomplish this with a custom `UIActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) (emphasis mine):

> ## init(activityItems:applicationActivities:)
>
> ...
>
> #### activityItems
>
> The array of data objects on which to perform the activity. The type of objects in the array is variable and dependent on the data your application manages. For example, the data might consist of one or more string or image objects representing the currently selected content.
>
> **Instead of actual data objects, the objects in this array can be objects that adopt the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol, such as `UIActivityItemProvider` objects.** Source and provider objects act as proxies for the corresponding data in situations where you do not want to provide that data until it is needed. Note that you should not reuse an activity view controller object that includes a `UIActivityItemProvider` object in its `activityItems` array.

Try implementing your own subclass of [`UIActivityItemProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemprovider) to provide the data on-demand.

Comment: Thanks sounds promising. If you know of any example code it would be appreciated. But reading full documentation at the moment.

Comment: Found UIActivityItemProvider example on SO. Reading.

Comment: Hmm based on the example, it is returning a NSData object that is instantiated by a URL so I don't think that will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581389/how-do-i-use-uiactivityitemprovider-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-with-uiacti

Comment: I need the user to be able to copy the file somehow (like AirDrop). Shame I have to return a NSData object since the whole file isn't needed to be loaded to RAM to simply copy the blocks.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I believe you can also return an `NSImage`, which will at least (typically) be a compressed image, unlike a raw bitmap stored as `Data`. A billion pixels is only a gigabyte, and probably compresses down to several 10s of MB. Might be plausible.

Comment: From reading the docs, I couldn't actually get a good sense of what kind of result types are exceptable. Certainly `NSURL`s, `NSString`s, `NSData` and `NSImage` objects, but IDK about what others might be possible.

Comment: oops, I meant `UIImage`* in both cases

Comment: The images aren't limited to a single gigapixel though. Multi-gigapixels. The image is already compressed.

Comment: It sounds like you are suggesting that a UIActivityItemProvider can provide URLs, and are not required to return NSData?

Comment: P.S. 1 gigapixel image weighs in around 1GB compressed.

Comment: "he image is already compressed." Oh RIP, that's pretty rough. I was thinking the NSData you were talking about was an uncompressed bitmap (which are bafflingly large, JPEG and the discrete cosine transform more generally, is a miracle technology lol)

Comment: "It sounds like you are suggesting that a UIActivityItemProvider can provide URLs, and are not required to return NSData?" I think so, but IDK if that could point to an item on disk. I was basing this off a quick/dirty skim of how people were using this API in public repos on GitHub: https://cs.github.com/?scopeName=All+repos&scope=&q=%22var+item%22+path%3A%2F**%2F*rovider.swift

Comment: So I'm trying to pass 1GB data read from the image to the Activity Controller, the menu shows up, but if I attempt to use AirDrop it does nothing, no errors (well other than the usual warnings). Besides passing Data do I need to give it a MIME type or something?

Comment: The git link you provided seems to be obfuscated.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Oh the special chars got parsed badly. How is this [link](https://cs.github.com/?scopeName=All+repos&scope=&q=%22var+item%22+path%3A%2F**%2F*rovider.swift)?

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either. I searched for "Arovider.swift github" but can't find it.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock You need to be logged in and enable the GitHub search preview (https://github.blog/2021-12-08-improving-github-code-search/). If you don't have access, you can approximate it with [the non-beta search UI](https://github.com/search?q=%22var+item%3A+Any%22+extension%3Aswift++filename%3A*provider.swift&type=Code)

Comment: So, I can use a NSFileCoordinator to get it to copy the file with the AirDrop, but, only if the URL has the extension "zip" instead of "jpg". Then the Mac thinks its a zip file, which of course it isn't. Ugh.

Comment: First time learning about `NSFileCoordinator`. I'm afraid we've hit the limit of my current knowledge. I hope I started you off in the right direction, though!

Comment: Mmm not really (not subclassing a `UIActivityItemProvider`), but I appreciate you trying to help.